# Are the summed medians of m datasets the median of the summed dataset?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

We have *m* datasets of *n* elements, where each element represents the grade of a student (from 1 to 10) for a given test. We are told that student Peter always achieves a test score that is the median of the class' results for a given test; if we would form a new dataset of the summed test scores for each student in the class, can we argue that Peter's summed score will again be the median of this dataset?

My intuition says we can, but I have a hard time materializing this into a concrete proof or argument. It would seem strange to me that the sum of each median would not be the median of this summed dataset (but this is obviously not a proof).

Comment: Try some examples and start simple: 3 students and 2 tests. Make peter score second on both tests and vary the scores of the other two students. Does peter stay the median when you sum each student's two test scores?

Comment: You could say that for means (assuming everybody took every test)